# how to convert canvas as png when multiple images drawn using drawimage

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, drawimage, todataurl

How do I render a canvas as an image with multiple image drawn on it and the image which I used to draw is cross origin.

While doing `toDataURL()` the image which I draw isn't coming.
Thanks in advance

this is my code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
baseimage = new Image();
baseimage.src = '' + data.picture.data.url + '';
baseimage.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(baseimage, 1, 1);
}
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Comment: You've got to make this call once all your images are drawn, i.e after the last onload event has fired.

Comment: I'm doing this only after the images are drawn

Comment: No. Your image loads  asynchrounously. Everything outside the onload callback will be called first, including the toDataURL call, then, only when the js will be freed and the image will have finished to load, your image will be drawn.

Comment: Han! This is a better dupe target : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Thanks for your help my friend.@kaiido